# How do I deal with special characters while using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping some websites that are in spanish and have some special characters like: ñ or ó. I´m using this code but when I export the csv file to excel the special characters do not appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGdyh.png)

This are some examples of how the file is seen in excel afterwards. Instead of ñ it appears Ã±.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNHD.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should be fine.The problem is that Excel opens the csv files with cp1252 by default, while Python stores the file in utf-8. Computers can only store numbers, and the operating system and softwares use a special table called character encoding to find out how to translate numbers to letters and characters.CP1252 and utf-8 are two of many character encoding standards. In this case, ñ has a utf-8 encoding 0xC3 0xB1, while in cp1252 it is interpreted as Ã±.

If you want to open csv file with utf-8, you should select File-Import in Excel, than choose Unicode(UTF-8) in File Origin dropdown menu.